# Ubuntu 18.04 won't start after dual boot installation with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, nvidia

I have a problem with my HP Pavilion. After many repeated clean installations (using gparted and installation from the live version), I can start my linux only in Recovery Mode. I tried, when in recovery mode, to repair eventually damaged packages (dpkg). But when I start in normal mode, I can log in Ubuntu, but every things freeze. **I can only move the mouse, I got black screen, and the keyboard stopped working (I cannot enter tty)**

These are the logs from the system using the command:

```
sudo grep -Pi "(critical|err|fail|fatal)" /var/log/syslog /var/log/syslog.1 /var/log/boot.log
```

This is the output:

```
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx systemd-udevd[429]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx systemd-udevd[429]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.004000] DMAR-IR: Use 'intremap=no_x2apic_optout' to override the BIOS setting.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.062122] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.205941] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315060] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315126] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315190] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315253] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315317] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315380] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315443] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315507] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.316229] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_0_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_1_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_2_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_3_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_4_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx gpu-manager[769]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx gpu-manager[769]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx udisksd[770]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    1.036677] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    1.115899] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   10.635364] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   13.462932] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   13.757988] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   13.757990] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   14.466039] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx udisksd[770]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:30 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   40.118446] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:23:07 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   77.837583] nouveau: DRM:00000000:0000c06f: detach ce0 failed, -110
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:23:07 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   77.837585] nouveau: DRM:0004c1b5:0000c1b5: suspend failed with -110
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
 grep: /var/log/syslog.1: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.004000] DMAR-IR: Use 'intremap=no_x2apic_optout' to override the BIOS setting.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.062122] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.205941] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315060] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315126] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315190] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315253] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315317] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315380] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315443] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.315507] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    0.316229] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_0_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_1_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_2_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_3_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx thermald[735]: sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_4_hyst
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx gpu-manager[769]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx gpu-  manager[769]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx udisksd[770]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    1.036677] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [    1.115899] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   10.635364] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   13.462932] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   13.757988] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   13.757990] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   14.466039] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:15 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx udisksd[770]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:19 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx wpa_supplicant[764]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:22:30 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   40.118446] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:23:07 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   77.837583] nouveau: DRM:00000000:0000c06f: detach ce0 failed, -110
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 17:23:07 kai-HP-Pavilion-Power-Laptop-15-cb0xx kernel: [   77.837585] nouveau: DRM:0004c1b5:0000c1b5: suspend failed with -110
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
grep: /var/log/syslog.1: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to install the proprietary drivers (**nvidia-driver-390 instead of xserver-xorg**) but It's the same. The distribution fails to start in normal mode.

Here are my VGAs specs:

```
   *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff     memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b4000000-b407ffff

  *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

As processor I have an intel i7
16GB RAM
I have two hard disk, one is an SSD with 128GB on which I have installed windows 10, and a mechanical one, with 1TB, on which I created a partition for ubuntu, with 200 GB space (100 GB for / and 100 GB for /home plus 5 GB for thw SWAP area)

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance. Before asking me to try different distributions: I have already tried Ubuntu 16.4 and Linux Mint, which had the same problems. Grubs works perfectly.

Comment: Recovery mode uses nomodeset boot parameter. So may be video driver issue as nomodeset is only required until you correctly install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. If different or wrong version, you must purge old one or you have conflicts. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it & https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: @oldfred thanks. There wasn't the exact solution to my problem, but with some turn around I was able to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone bumping in this problem (this problem occurs with UEFI BIOS Systems) , I solved in this way:

- Because I could not enter Ubuntu (black screen and everything was blocked) I entered the Recovery Mode (You can enter in it from grub interface or setting nomodeset by pressing `E` from the grub interface, changing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` )
- Then I added the repository for my nvidia drivers:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- I then installed my nvidia drivers:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
  ```
- Then I rebooted the system, entered the UEFI BIOS and disabled the `SECURE BOOT` option

any details found here [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)